# SQL Server 2019 : Subquery Join won't execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, left-join, sql-server-2019

I have to design a report which will be a list of a bunch of overlapping data from the same table.

I have to start with the `Project` table because for the report `@ProjectId` is the only thing you get as an anchor.

In the `RessourceBookings` table are all bookings and some are overlapping like

- Project A books resource B 24.01., 10 a.m. to 6 p.m.
- Project C books resource B 24.01., 11 a.m. to 1 p.m
- Project D books resource B 24.01., 1 p.m. to 4 p.m

These are the one I have to filter for and list all those booking conflicts for Project A.

This is the code I came up with at the moment. I didn't shorten it because I want to show that there are a few dependencies from some tables, which makes it a bit complicated (at least for me). If there are other parts besides the main problem which could be optimised, I would be happy to learn.

```sql
DECLARE @ProjectId INT = 8501

SELECT 
    p.Id AS 'Project-ID'
    ,p.Name AS 'Project-Name'
    ,p.Info AS 'Project-Info'
    ,pc.Name AS 'Project-Color'
    ,upr.DocumentName AS 'Project-Responsible'
    ,r.ResourceName AS 'Ressource-Name'
    ,r.Info AS 'Ressource-Info'
    ,CASE WHEN ugrr.ResourceRoleId IN (4,7)
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END AS 'Ressource-Availability'
    ,r.Quantity AS 'Booking-Quantity'
    ,rb.Start AS 'Booking-Start'
    ,rb.[End] AS 'Booking-End'
    ,pat.Name AS 'Booking-Action'
    ,rb.IsOption AS 'Booking-State'
    ,rb.OptionRequestAccepted AS 'Booking-Response'
    ,q2.ProjectId AS 'Conflict-Project-ID'
    ,q2.Name AS 'Conflict-Project-Name'
    ,q2.DocumentName AS 'Conflict-Project-Responsible'
    ,q2.Start AS 'Conflict-Start'
    ,q2.[End] AS 'Conflict-End'
    ,q2.IsOption AS 'Conflict-State'
FROM 
    Projects p
LEFT JOIN 
    ProjectColors pc ON pc.Id = p.ProjectColorId
LEFT JOIN 
    Users upr ON upr.Id = p.ResponsibleUserId
LEFT JOIN 
    ResourceBookings rb ON rb.ProjectId = p.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    Resources r ON r.Id = rb.ResourceId
LEFT JOIN 
    ProjectActions pa ON pa.Id = rb.ProjectActionId
LEFT JOIN 
    ProjectActionTypes pat ON pat.Id = pa.ProjectActionTypeId
LEFT JOIN 
    UserGroupResourceRoles ugrr ON ugrr.ResourceId = r.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         p2.ProjectId
         ,p2.Name
         ,upr2.DocumentName
         ,rb2.Start
         ,rb2.[End]
         ,rb2.IsOption
     FROM 
         ResourceBookings rb2
     LEFT JOIN 
         Projects p2 ON p2.Id = rb2.ProjectId
     LEFT JOIN 
         Users upr2 ON upr2.Id = p2.ResponsibleUserId
     WHERE 
         rb2.ResourceId = r.Id
         AND (rb2.Start BETWEEN DATEADD(s, +1, rb.Start) AND DATEADD(s, -1, rb.[End])
              OR rb2.[End] BETWEEN DATEADD(s, +1, rb.Start) AND DATEADD(s, -1, rb.[End])
              OR DATEADD(s,+1,rb.Start) BETWEEN rb2.Start AND rb2.[End])) q2
WHERE 
    p.Id = @ProjectId
    AND rb.Start >= SysDateTime()
    AND ugrr.UserGroupId = 11
    AND (SELECT Count(rb2.Id) - 1
         FROM ResourceBookings rb2
         WHERE rb2.ResourceId = r.Id
           AND (rb2.Start BETWEEN DATEADD(s, +1, rb.Start) AND DATEADD(s, -1, rb.[End])
                OR rb2.[End] BETWEEN DATEADD(s, +1, rb.Start) AND DATEADD(s, -1, rb.[End])
                OR DATEADD(s, +1, rb.Start) BETWEEN rb2.Start AND rb2.[End])) > 0
```

My goal is something like:

| Project-ID | Project-Name | [...] | Conflict-Project-ID | Conflict-Project-Name | [...] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Project A | [...] | 2 | Project B | [...] |
| 1 | Project A | [...] | 3 | Project C | [...] |
| 1 | Project A | [...] | 4 | Project D | [...] |

Without the whole q2 parts, it works well to list all the information for Project A.

The errors are:

> Wrong syntax near the WHERE-keyword.. Native error: 156. SQLSTATE: 42000. Severity 15. Msg State 1. Line 76.
>
> Wrong syntax near ">".. Native error: 102. SQLSTATE: 42000. Severity 15. MsgState 1. Line 87.

Without the subquery join, it works well but I think I need that there. I've googled the last two days but can't find any solution. In my eyes it seems correct.

I can't change the tables or their content. I have to deal with the setup. So temporary tables are not an option (which maybe could help).

*(But please no single-word technical-term-answers. I'm not a developer, I have just to work with these kind of things. I'm willing to learn but it's a bit hard without a professional background)*

---

***Edit:***
For clarifications, here is a picture of the table `ResourceBookings` (top) and bottom the "goal" of the query if `@ProjectId = 8525`

[image]

Comment: the error is from the last subquery. you cannot use aggregate functions in where clause, instead use having count(q2.id)>1. for this you need to add rb2.id in your left join subquery ------ also you are missing a join condition in the last left join, it simply ends with q2 and starts the where clause starts. Even if you fix the where issue, the join will throw error

Comment: Side points: it seems your `LEFT JOIN`s should probably be `INNER`. You might find it better to use window functions rather than that subquery. [`BETWEEN` is a bad idea to use on dates.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) Use `[]` to quote column names, not `''`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the reply! `INNER JOIN` seems to be right there, I will keep this im mind. I can't follow what you mean with `You might find it better to use window functions rather than that subquery.` What is the difference in using `[]` then `''`?

Comment: You can use a windowed count to achieve the same thing as the subquery: `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rb.ResourceId)` or something like that. Using `''` to quote column names is bad, it can cause unintended results in some cases, see for example https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194224/impact-of-quotes-in-t-sql-for-column-name

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @ProjectId INT = 8501

SELECT p.Id AS 'Project-ID'
    ,p.Name AS 'Project-Name'
    ,p.Info AS 'Project-Info'
    ,pc.Name AS 'Project-Color'
    ,upr.DocumentName AS 'Project-Responsible'
    ,r.ResourceName AS 'Ressource-Name'
    ,r.Info AS 'Ressource-Info'
    ,CASE WHEN ugrr.ResourceRoleId IN (4,7)
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END AS 'Ressource-Availability'
    ,r.Quantity AS 'Booking-Quantity'
    ,rb.Start AS 'Booking-Start'
    ,rb.[End] AS 'Booking-End'
    ,pat.Name AS 'Booking-Action'
    ,rb.IsOption AS 'Booking-State'
    ,rb.OptionRequestAccepted AS 'Booking-Response'
    ,q2.ProjectId AS 'Conflict-Project-ID'
    ,q2.Name AS 'Conflict-Project-Name'
    ,q2.DocumentName AS 'Conflict-Project-Responsible'
    ,q2.Start AS 'Conflict-Start'
    ,q2.[End] AS 'Conflict-End'
    ,q2.IsOption AS 'Conflict-State'
    

FROM Projects p
LEFT JOIN ProjectColors pc ON pc.Id = p.ProjectColorId
LEFT JOIN Users upr ON upr.Id = p.ResponsibleUserId
LEFT JOIN ResourceBookings rb ON rb.ProjectId = p.Id
LEFT JOIN Resources r ON r.Id = rb.ResourceId
LEFT JOIN ProjectActions pa ON pa.Id = rb.ProjectActionId
LEFT JOIN ProjectActionTypes pat ON pat.Id = pa.ProjectActionTypeId
LEFT JOIN UserGroupResourceRoles ugrr ON ugrr.ResourceId = r.Id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p2.Id as id2
                ,p2.Name
                ,upr2.DocumentName
                ,rb2.Start
                ,rb2.[End]
                ,rb2.IsOption
                ,rb2.id
                ,rb2.ProjectId as rb_pid
                ,count(rb2.id) as id_count
            FROM ResourceBookings rb2
            LEFT JOIN Projects p2 ON p2.Id = rb2.ProjectId
            LEFT JOIN Users upr2 ON upr2.Id = p2.ResponsibleUserId
            LEFT JOIN Resources r ON r.Id = rb2.ResourceId
            WHERE rb2.ResourceId = r.Id
                AND (
                    rb2.Start BETWEEN DateAdd(s,+1,rb2.Start) AND DateAdd(s,-1,rb2.[End])
                    OR rb2.[End] BETWEEN DateAdd(s,+1,rb2.Start) AND DateAdd(s,-1,rb2.[End])
                    OR DateAdd(s,+1,rb2.Start) BETWEEN rb2.Start AND rb2.[End]
                )
                group by p2.Id
                ,p2.Name
                ,upr2.DocumentName
                ,rb2.Start
                ,rb2.[End]
                ,rb2.IsOption
                ,rb2.id
                ,rb2.ProjectId 
            ) q2
on q2.rb_pid = p.Id

WHERE p.Id = @ProjectId
    AND rb.Start >= SysDateTime()
    AND ugrr.UserGroupId = 11
    AND q2.id_count > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Well tried far longer and it seems I was overcomplicating things with the subquery.

Without it and with a few more Joins it works like a charm.

For clarifying why I "ignored" some of the tips I got:

- `INNER` wasn't the right choice. It would mess with the results badly (probably because the tables aren't great designed and have many overlapping headers without correlation...)
- `[]` instead of `''` will probably the better choice after reading a bit more about it. Will fix that in the future in my queries.
- The `window functions` seems powerful and less resource-hungry and I will look into it but at this point I didn't fully understand them well enough.

I think I will try to optimise it again after reading ad understanding more about the named tips but for now this works for me:

```sql
DECLARE @ProjectId INT = 6290

SELECT
    p.Id AS 'Project-ID'
    ,p.Name AS 'Project-Name'
    ,p.Info AS 'Project-Info'
    ,pc.Name AS 'Project-Color'
    ,upr.DocumentName AS 'Project-Responsible'
    ,r.ResourceName AS 'Resource-Name'
    ,r.Info AS 'Resource-Info'
    ,CASE WHEN ugrr.ResourceRoleId IN (4,7)
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END AS 'Resource-Availability'
    ,rb.Quantity AS 'Booking-Quantity'
    ,rb.Start AS 'Booking-Start'
    ,rb.[End] AS 'Booking-End'
    ,pat.Name AS 'Booking-Action'
    ,rb.IsOption AS 'Booking-State'
    ,rb.OptionRequestAccepted AS 'Booking-Response'
    ,rb2.ProjectId AS 'Conflict-Project-ID'
    ,p2.Name AS 'Conflict-Project-Name'
    ,pc2.Name AS 'Conflict-Project-Color'
    ,upr2.DocumentName AS 'Conflict-Project-Responsible'
    ,rb2.Start AS 'Conflict-Start'
    ,rb2.[End] AS 'Conflict-End'
    ,pat2.Name AS 'Conflict-Booking-Action'
    ,rb2.IsOption AS 'Conflict-Booking-State' 
    ,rb2.Quantity AS 'Conflict-Booking-Quantity'

FROM Projects p
LEFT JOIN ProjectColors pc ON pc.Id = p.ProjectColorId
LEFT JOIN Users upr ON upr.Id = p.ResponsibleUserId
LEFT JOIN ResourceBookings rb ON rb.ProjectId = p.Id
LEFT JOIN Resources r ON r.Id = rb.ResourceId
LEFT JOIN ProjectActions pa ON pa.Id = rb.ProjectActionId
LEFT JOIN ProjectActionTypes pat ON pat.Id = pa.ProjectActionTypeId
LEFT JOIN UserGroupResourceRoles ugrr ON ugrr.ResourceId = r.Id
/* Doubles for Conflicts */
LEFT JOIN ResourceBookings rb2 ON rb2.ResourceId = rb.ResourceId
LEFT JOIN Projects p2 ON p2.Id = rb2.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN ProjectColors pc2 ON pc2.Id = p2.ProjectColorId
LEFT JOIN ProjectActions pa2 ON pa2.Id = rb2.ProjectActionId
LEFT JOIN ProjectActionTypes pat2 ON pat2.Id = pa2.ProjectActionTypeId
LEFT JOIN Users upr2 ON upr2.Id = p2.ResponsibleUserId

WHERE
    p.Id = @ProjectId
    AND rb.Start >= SysDateTime()
    AND ugrr.UserGroupId = 11
    AND rb.Id <> rb2.Id
    AND (
            (
                rb2.Start >= rb.Start
                AND rb2.Start <= rb.[End]
            )
        OR
            (
                rb2.[End] >= rb.Start
                AND rb2.[End] <= rb.[End]
            )
        OR
            (
                rb.Start >= rb2.Start
                AND rb.Start <= rb2.[End]
            )
        )
```